# How to prevent book class from vertically justifying the contents?

Tags: vertical-alignment

If we use the `book` class, the output looks like the following screenshot.

[image]

But if we use the `article` class, the output looks better as follows.

[image]

The MWE is given as follows. Note: please enable `-shell-escape`!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}% please change to article and compare the output.

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{"article sample.tex"}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{showexpl}

\lstset
{
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\hbox{},
}

\newcount\x

\newcommand\MyLTXinputExample[2][2mm]{%
% #1: length of gap,
% #2: filename with .tex, 
    \lstinputlisting[caption=\url{#2.tex}]{"#2.tex"}
    \bgroup
        \parskip=#1\relax
        \fboxsep=0pt
        \pdfximage{#2.pdf}%
        \x=0
        \loop
            \ifnum\x<\pdflastximagepages
                \advance\x by 1
                \noindent\hfill
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-4\fboxrule-#1\relax,page=\x]{"#2"}}%                     
            \ifnum\x<\pdflastximagepages
                \advance\x by 1
                \hfill
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-4\fboxrule-#1\relax,page=\x]{"#2"}}%
            \fi
                \hfill\null\par
        \repeat
    \egroup
}

\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{pdflatex "article sample"}
\MyLTXinputExample{article sample}
\end{document}
```

How to prevent `book` class from vertically justifying the contents? In other words, I want to use the `book` class but its output (only the justification is under consideration) must look like the output that `article` class produces.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put a `\raggedbottom` into your preamble.

Comment: Today I have learnt a new thing, `\raggedbottom`. Thank you!