# Float goes to bottom of page even with forced 'H' placement

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

I have a certain document with a few tables one after another. Each table is in its own subsubsection. The peculiar thing about these tables is that two tables can fit on a page with a subsubsection title, but only one can fit with the section, subsection and subsubsection. With just one table:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection*{Table 1}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\scalebox{0.65}{
\begin{tabular}{|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|}
    \hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Table 1 Caption}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

I get a perfectly fine output:

[image: just one table]

However, as soon as I have multiple tables:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection*{Table 1}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\scalebox{0.65}{
\begin{tabular}{|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|}
    \hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Table 1 Caption}
\end{table}

\subsubsection*{Table 2}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\scalebox{0.65}{
\begin{tabular}{|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|}
    \hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Table 2 Caption}
\end{table}

\subsubsection*{Table 3}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\scalebox{0.65}{
\begin{tabular}{|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|}
    \hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Table 3 Caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The pages look like this:

[image: three tables page one]
[image: three tables page two]

I want the first page to stay exactly the same way as it was before. I found one solution, i.e. adding a '\clearpage' just after the first '\end{table}', which gives me:

[image: three tables with clearpage page one]
[image: three tables with clearpage page two]

However, this solution is not elegant enough for me, since it involves doing something specifically for the first table, whereas the tables are, in all other ways, equivalent.

Is there a solution which automatically adjusts(forces) the tables to stay on top of the page and not 'gravitate' towards its following tables?

I already tried \vfill{} and \vspace{\fill} with no success!

Comment: if there's not enough text to fill the page, *something* is going to be shoved down to give a "flush bottom", and that happens to be your table.  use `\raggedbottom` to ignore the fact that the page is "short".

Comment: Which document class do you use? And, do you load any packages other than (presumably) the `float` package to manage the appearance of floats and their captions?

Comment: The document class is book, and I load the float, graphicx and array packages, as the code snippets show!

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How to prevent the paragraphs to spread out over the page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33977/5764); [How to prevent `book` class from vertically justifying the contents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98327/5764)